# Adding methods to JSON read object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to convert json data into objects with methods attached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838219/easiest-way-to-convert-json-data-into-objects-with-methods-attached)
>   [Casting plain objects to function instances (“classes”) in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810028/casting-plain-objects-to-function-instances-classes-in-javascript)

I have an object as follows:

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.talk = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

I create objects as follows:

```
var person = new Person("Test", 20);
```

These objects are then saved as JSON (stringify) in browser's local storage

When I read the object back, I get the data, but I don't get the methods attached, i.e. talk() is not available as a method any more. How do I attach them again?

```
window.localStorage["person"] = JSON.stringify(new Person('Test', 20));
var person = window.localStorage["person"];
person.talk("Hello");
```

The error I get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object {"name":"Test","age":20} has no method 'talk'
```

Obvious, right? But how do I tell that this is a Person object? Or should I just copy the attributes from the read object onto a new Person object, is that the only way?

Comment: You do realize you are reading back a string.

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a new instance and assign the values you parsed from the JSON serialisation.

Comment: @Musa, yes so I thought, but if you look at what comes back, it looks like a JSON object and not a string! Anyways, I guess I will have to live with copying of attributes.

Comment: @Musa, sorry, ignore me. While creating this example, I forgot to do the JSON.parse, so yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Or should I just copy the attributes from the read object onto a new Person object, is that the only way?`

Yes, make a PersonFactory or use a similar design pattern to construct a new Person object from the json data representing a Person.